# does app give different device token on re-installing again

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I remember, the device token never changes upon re-installing for iPhone.

However these days (especially on iOS 9), I noticed that device token is changing if I re-install the app.

Is this setting is done by Apple or I am missing anything?

I have to know this because this is very important for me as I am sending push based for specific users to inform their updates.

Also for no reason there are un-wanted many device tokens.

***Note***

*I am calling below webservice in App Delegate*

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    // sending it to online database for my record
}
```

Comment: yes, i also face the same problem, but deleting the app,derived data and build file and then installing  again solves my problem.

Comment: @PratikShah : I don't have any problem.. I just want to be sure that this is happening by Apple only and I am not doing anything wrong... bcz of this, I want to delete un-wanted device-tokens and I have to find a way for that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes on iOS9 Apple says that Device Token might change each time your app is installed. So the best way is to reregister the Device token on **each launch**.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1) is a link to Apples documentation about changing device token

Comment: As I said in my question, I am already registering every-time I open app... & I remember it never happen before...

Comment: i think its new in iOS 9

Answer (score 1):

You need to find your own way to track user. Here is issues with your approach and suggested vendor identifier:

- Device `push token` can change at any moment. You can track this change during application launch and ask server to switch tokens, but messages which will be send till this moment on old token will be lost.
- `identifierForVendor` - also very unreliable source of unique identifier, because it will change in a lot of cases.

  > The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.

For single device you can use Keychain as source of persistent identifier storage. You can generate for user new unique identifier (for example with `NSUUID`) and store it in Keychain (if not exist yet). If access group will be configured for stored item and reused with all your application - you will have access to stored unique identifier from your applications on user device. If properly configured, item in Keychain will be stored in encrypted user device backups and even will be restored on his new device.

Comment: Also if the keychain is used the item will persist across app deletion and re-installation, even all apps of a group.

Comment: @zaph Yes! This persistent stuff caused a lot of pain to us when we used **MKStoreKit** and didn't get why we don't see proper interface after application re-install. Feature was purchased and active. When we gone deeper into his code, we found Keychain and learned a lesson from this situation about how Keychain is useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it might be changed when each time app is installed. you need to update the device_token on every launch of app.

Answer (score -1):

rtfm:
"The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor."

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor

Comment: but my app is coming from same vendor... when i re-install from app store, it always gives me new device id...